# how to prevent auto deletion collection records from Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello all I got stuck somewhere,  I am working on mongodb with node.js where my collection data deleted automatically after 1 year on certain date and I want to stop that permanently how can I do that ? I have checked the available material on google but didn't got much success please help me friends ...

I have checked the index in one of my collection and it is showing data like this . Can you please tell me its is having TTL index or not

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "firstfive.teachers"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "firstname_lastname_text",
        "weights" : {
            "firstName" : 1,
            "lastName" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "ns" : "firstfive.teachers",
        "textIndexVersion" : 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

most likely you have TTL (time to limit) index defined on collection you're working with (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-ttl/)

yu can check it by running `db.your_collection.getIndexes()` (it will be one with `expireAfterSeconds`) in mongo shell. 
as any other index it can be removed - but do it carefully, apparently someone did it deliberately

Comment: Thanks for the answer !! let me check the link and i will let u know if any help needed

Comment: #djaszczurowski i found this command in google `db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, ttlMonitorEnabled:false});` will it work ?

Comment: it should. Personally I've never needed to use it, but according to the documentation it works https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/parameters/#param.ttlMonitorEnabled

Comment: Can you please tell me how to remove TTL from mongodb's collection so it wont remove any more data in future ?

Comment: first, find what's the name of the index. To do it type: `db.your_collection_name_here.getIndexes()` - it'll be the one with expireAfterSeconds attribute. In order to remove the TTL index type `db.your_collection_name_here.dropIndex("index_name")`

Comment: i have just update the question after running `db.your_collection_name_here.getIndexes()` this command i am getting the above result please let me know if it is having any TTL index

Comment: that's surprising, because it's missing. is there a chance there is a separate process that is run on a daily basis and manually deletes the documents?

Comment: actaully it deletes only one time in the year on 1st of june or may be 31st of may

Comment: so maybe there is an additional background process that removes these documents?